# issue with contains() to match two strings

Tags: java, string, contains, stringtokenizer

Considering we have a `String` that contains three words, e.g, `"kids story book"` which we added each of these words into a `HashMap<String, Integer>` while the String part contains the word and the Integer part contains the position of word in the String, i.e, 1, 2 and 3. Assume also that there is another same type of `HashMap` which is field by a serious of grouped words. Consider each group of words have a common Integer value as an ID which indicates they belong together. My aim is to look into the second `HashMap` in order to find any Strings that contains either of `kids`, `story` or `book` and then returning the word together with its unique integer ID. Here is my code for doing so:

```
       String keyword="kids story book";
       static HashMap<String, Integer> tempp = new HashMap<>();
       static HashMap<String, Integer> stringToint = new HashMap<>();

                 //File is .txt file which contains some characters at each line
                 FileOutputStream Fcategorize=new FileOutputStream(File,true);

          FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(File);

          BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

String line = bufferReader.readLine();


        for(int i = 0; line != null; i++){
        if( header(i).equals(line)){
            while( (line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null && ! Footer(i).equals( line ) )
               {


stringToint.put(line, i);
 }
              }

        }



    StringTokenizer start=new StringTokenizer(keyword);

    for(int i=-1; i<=start.countTokens();i++)
    {
        String temp=start.nextToken();
        tempp.put(temp, i);
    }

    Set<String> fkeys = stringToint.keySet();
    Iterator<String> fit = fkeys.iterator();


    Set<String> Lkeys =tempp.keySet();
    Iterator<String> sit = Lkeys.iterator();


    for(int i=0 ; i<tempp.size() ; i++)
    {
    nextToken=sit.next();
    while (fit.hasNext()){
                    String featurename = fit.next();

               if(featurename.contains(nextToken))
               {

              //Do something
               }

           }

    }
```

There are three problems: First, the first `HashMap` does contain all the three words but if I use the console to print results, it only prints the matching for the first item of `HashMap` and not all the three (while there are other matches for all of the three words). Second, as it is obvious in the code, I started the loop from `i=-1` and that is because if I use `i=0` it will not add all the three characters to the `HashMap` and in this case, the order of words in the String will not be the same as the order of them in the `HashMap` and finally, even for the items in the first position of the `HashMap`, it even does not return all the matching, used by `contains()`. I checked manually and I found out there are more results to be returned while it did not happen.

Comment: Please provide a small runnable example of your problem which contains code about the way both maps are filled.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd problem is that you don't reset the `fit` iterator on each word search (in your code, reset means initializing a new one).
Actually, you need to initialize it each time inside your `for` loop

```
for(int i=0 ; i<tempp.size() ; i++)
{
    nextToken=sit.next();
    fit = fkeys.iterator();
    while (fit.hasNext()){
         ....
```

Comment: But I am wondering why `Iterator<String> fit=fkeys.iterator()` is useless? I mean if I remove `=fkeys.iterator()` from it, it still performs right. In addition, the IDE shows `Unused  assignment` notification for it too.

Comment: Yes, it's because it is not used as you reinitialize it inside for loop. Just declare the variable Iterator<String> fit; or set it to null ::  Iterator<String> fit = null;

Comment: But in some other cases, I used like that and it worked like fine, out of a `While` loop. Is it different thing or what? I am a bit of confused.

Comment: You need to initialize an iterator each you need to loop using it. Here, you have a while loop, if you didn't initialize it before while loop, the iterator would continue from its previous state. All in all, if you need it only for one time it's fine, but, if you need it for independent loops (as now with the while) you need to reinitialize it each time before each independent loop.

Comment: you mean the situation for `while` and `for` is the same?

Comment: Each while-loop is independent; for each nextToken=sit.next(); you need to iterate again from the beginning!

Comment: no no, I dont mean in this code. In some other program, I used same way to compare content of two HashMaps but instead of a for-loop,  used a while-loop. something like this `    Set<String> fkeys = firstFeatures.keySet();
        Iterator<String> fit = fkeys.iterator();
        while (fit.hasNext()) {
            String featurename = fit.next();
            boolean containKey = secondFeatures.containsKey(featurename);
            if (containKey) {
                           }
        }`

Comment: To avoid any issues, always initialize the iterator just before the loop that uses it. This way you are safe! So, your provided example is safe too.

Comment: This problem usually arises when there are nested loops (eg a while-loop inside a for-loop). If you always need to iterate in the whole Set on the while-loop, you need to initialize it inside for-loop and before while{

Answer (score 1):

To solve your second problem: you should store the value of start.countTokens(); into another variable first, instead of evaluating it in every loop. Because **every time you call start.nextToken(), start.countTokens() reduces by 1.**

**Edit**: you can use **LinkedHashMap** to maintain the order of the entries in the way they are added to the map.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> tempp = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // use LinkedHashMap to maintain order

    String keyword = "kids story book";
    StringTokenizer start = new StringTokenizer(keyword);
    int count = start.countTokens(); // save it to another variable

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String temp = start.nextToken();
        tempp.put(temp, i);
    }

    for (Map.Entry entry : tempp.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
    }
    // gives you
    // kids, 0
    // story, 1
    // book, 2
```

Comment: But the order is still an issue. the last one is at the first place. although having `i=2` but appears at the beginning of the `HashMap`. why is that so? The order is like `2`, `0` and then `1`

Comment: @lonesome HashMap doesn't maintain the order of the entries in the way they are added to the Map, if you want to maintain the order. Use LinkedHashMap. I have updated my answer

Comment: understood, thanks. get my +1 while I still did not get all problem solved in one answer.